# NGINX proxy_pass to Docker, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I have docker-compose with simple wordpress docker and mysql docker included:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXX
      MYSQL_DATABASE: XXX
      MYSQL_USER: XXX
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: XXX
    networks:
      - wpsite
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - './:/var/www/html'
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
```

It works correctly when I'm trying to access paths through localhost:8000, I get correct responses from that psecific url:

```
http://localhost:8000/test
http://localhost:8000/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/main.js
http://localhost:8000/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/image.svg
http://localhost:8000/wp-admin
```

All of them works correctly.

Then I prepared my nginx on server (not in docker) to proxy_pass all requestts to localhost:8000:

```
server {
    server_name myurl.com.pl;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myurl.com.pl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pmyurl.com.pl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = myurl.com.pl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name myurl.com.pl;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot 
}
```

But then I'm always getting redirect in url from myurl.com.pl => localhost ... with 302 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Issue was finally not related to nginx or docker itself. It was issue on wp-config side, where needs to be specified:`$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';`. Then it works as expected